# creating color themes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am making a simple calculator. However, I want the color theme to change every time the program is loaded (the theme doesn't change while the program is running). I have an array that stores UIColors that I'm using to change the background color, and that works fine. What I want is to also change the colors of the buttons and labels to match the theme. So when a red background is chosen (at random), all the buttons, text and labels have a red color theme. The next time the program is loaded, it has a yellow color theme; and so on and so forth. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: The answer depends on many factors such as how you create the UI components you want to have different colors. Start with good use of the appropriate UIAppearance proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UIAppearance` protocol to get an appearance proxy for each class that you want to customize, and call the appropriate methods to make your changes. For example:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[[UIButton appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

See [this NSCookbook recipe](http://nscookbook.com/2013/01/ios-programming-recipe-8-using-uiappearance-for-a-custom-look/) and read [the NSHipster article](http://nshipster.com/uiappearance/) for more detailed examples.